# Build a "feature - story mapping with release as the swimlanes" - how to deal with the release?

Tags: rally

I want to build a app shows up the follow board.[image: sample board]

So I create a custom html apps, the source code is listed here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>StoryMap</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0/sdk-debug.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {
                Ext.define('mycardcolumnheader', {
    extend:  Rally.ui.cardboard.ColumnHeader,
    alias: 'widget.mycardcolumnheader',

});

Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {

        //Fetch tree of items
    //  a) starting from item type in picker
    //  b) subject to a filter

    //The number of columns is related to the number of lowest level PI type items that are found
    //The header must show the top level (from the picker) and all the children
    //The user stories are shown in a vertical line below
    //Might want to introduce the concept of timebox in the vertical direction (for user stories)
    //The cards for the PIs should show the progress bars

    var ch = Ext.create( 'Ext.Container', {
    });

    var dTab = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
         items: [{
             xtype: 'rallycardboard',
             types: ['HierarchicalRequirement'],
//             columnConfig: { xtype: 'mycardcolumn', displayField: 'feat', valueField: 'fest' },
//             attribute: 'ScheduleState'
            attribute: 'Feature',
            rowConfig: { field: 'Release', sortDirection: 'ASC' },
            enableDragAndDrop: true
         }]
      });

    this.add(dTab);

    }
});


            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name:"StoryMap",
           parentRepos:""
            });

        });
    </script>



    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
  /* Add app styles here */
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It's very similar to what I want, but still have a small bug, I do not know how to fix it. the bug is if I choose the parent project, the board will show up the same release into multiple swimlanes. Here is a example.
[image: real case example]

this is probably because each Rally Project has its own Release and the App is not smart enough to recognize they are all logically the same Release.
If create Release 1 at the Parent Project level and cascade the Release to the child projects, Rally actually creates 3 Releases ... 1 for each project.  Our application happens to know that if the Release name, start date, and end dates match, they should be treated as a single Release.  It appears the App does not have this logic included in it.

But how to fix it? anyone could take a look?

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of expected behavior, mostly due to the fact that we never built the ability for the board to "bucket" the like releases into its rows or columns.

You'll probably need to override the [isMatchingRecord](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard-method-getRowFor) method on Rally.ui.cardboard.row.Row to be able to bucket the rows:

```
 //add this at the top of your app
 Ext.define('Rally.ui.cardboard.row.RowFix', {
     override: 'Rally.ui.cardboard.row.Row',

     isMatchingRecord: function(record) {
         return this.callParent(arguments) ||
             this.getValue().Name === (record.get('Release') && record.get('Release').Name);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Yeah, it group the same release name into one row.
But one small thing is, If the user story has not been planned into any release, then lost the row called "NONE", can you modify this method to add the NONE row back?